# Trying to copy cell format from one sheet to another, cell by cell

Tags: excel, vba

```
Sub Start()


Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet

Set ws1 = Sheets("1")
Set ws2 = Sheets("2")

Dim LastRow As Long, i As Long
LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).row

For i = 1 To LastRow

ws1.Range("D" & i).copy
ws2.Range("A2").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats

Next i

If ws1.Range("A" & i) = vbNullString Then
    Exit Sub
End If

End Sub
```

I'm trying to make it so this code pastes the interior fill from column D, Into Column A, unless there is  already interior fill present.

Any input appreciated.

---

Edit: I'm trying to copy the format (interior fill) from Sheet 1 and Sheet 2's Column A's (until the last row) and paste it to Sheet Column A. I'm trying to copy over once cell at a time, and ignore if there is already fill present in sheet 3, because my I dont want the format from sheets 1 and 2 to overwrite eachtoher.

Comment: It is unclear where you are taking the format(s) from? Is it from one cell (which one)? If not, how are the cells in both worksheets associated, does each row of one worksheet relate to the same row of the other? It is unclear in which worksheet the last row is calculated. Your code is currently copying the formats from many cells to one cell only. Maybe you want it the other way around. Please do clarify.

Comment: @VBasic2008 Edited for Clarity